# Assert that a function was executed

Tags: knockout.js, qunit

I am trying to unit test a Knockout JS extender function that subscribes to a `ko.observable` (causing it to run when the value changes). To test that it works correctly, I need to verify that the extender function was executed when the `ko.observable` was changed.

Here is my test so far:

```
test("ko.extenders.addFieldTrackingGA", function () {

    //arrange
    var testObservable = ko.observable(1).extend({
         addFieldTrackingGA: "Some button was clicked"
    });

    //act
    testObservable(5);

    //assert

});
```

My question is: How can I assert that ko.extenders.addFieldTrackingGA was executed when the observable was changed?

Here is the code that I want to confirm executed:

Knockoutextension:

```
ko.extenders.addFieldTrackingGA = function (target, option) {
    target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if (newValue) {
            qb.Utils.Analytics().trackEvent(qb.Utils.Analytics().product,
                                            "form click",
                                            option,
                                            false);
        }
    });
    return target;
};
```

qb.analystics:

```
 /**
 * Event = e.g. 'trackEvent'
 * Category = e.g. 'error_message_home'
 * Action = fieldName
 * Label = 'some message'
 * ignoreMultiple = false | true | {blank} - if true, gtm actions that are fired more than once will be ignored, defaults to true.
 */
var _pushGTM = function (event, category, action, label, ignoreMultiple) {
    if (typeof dataLayer !== 'undefined') { // Add test for dataLayer as breaking Qunit

        ignoreMultiple = ignoreMultiple === undefined ? true : ignoreMultiple;

        if (_.contains(pushedGTM, action + label) && ignoreMultiple) { // Make sure event doesn't get fired more than once, only fire it the first time
            return;
        }

        var gtmObject = {
            'event': event,
            'eventDetails.category': category,  // Push the value depending on the form (car/house/contents)
            'eventDetails.action': action,      // Push the form field name.(If there is no field name push "No_field"
            'eventDetails.label': label         // Please push the exact error string. 
        }

        if (ignoreMultiple) {
            pushedGTM.push(action + label);
        }

        _pushGTMObject(gtmObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should realize that you have a pretty heavy dependency in your extender: qb.analytics. Currently you're (by side effect) also testing that, when you only *want* to test one *unit*: the extender.

I can give you at least three basic options to handle this:

1. Factor out the dendency on `qb` and inject it somehow into your extender. Your tests can then inject mocks that help with the assertion.
2. Use some kind of spy/mock framework like SinonJS. I'll admit, because of lack of experience with SinonJS and similar frameworks I'm not 100% sure if this approach will pay off.
3. Monkey patch `qb` in your tests to help with assertions.

The latter approach is a bit blunt, but it's straightforward. Here's how it would work:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var trackEventFn = function() { };

  QUnit.module("Mymodule", {
    beforeEach: function() {
      window.qb = {
        Utils: {
            Analytics: function() {
              return { trackEvent: trackEventFn };
            }
        }
      };
    }
  });

  QUnit.test("ko.extenders.addFieldTrackingGA", function(assert) {
    // arrange
    var testObservable = ko.observable(1).extend({
      addFieldTrackingGA: "Some button was clicked"
    });

    // prepare assertion    
    trackEventFn = function(prod, event, option, somebool) {
      assert.ok(true);
      // You can also assert on the argument values here
    }
    assert.expect(1); // Or more than 1, depending on the above

    // act
    testObservable(5);
  });

}());
```

---

Here's a full demo:

```js
window.qb = {
  Utils: {
    Analytics: function() {
      return { trackEvent: function() { } };
    }
  }
};

ko.extenders.addFieldTrackingGA = function (target, option) {
  target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      qb.Utils.Analytics().trackEvent(qb.Utils.Analytics().product,
                                      "form click",
                                      option,
                                      false);
    }
  });
  return target;
};

(function() {
  "use strict";

  var trackEventFn = function() { };

  QUnit.module("Mymodule", {
    beforeEach: function() {
      window.qb = {
        Utils: {
          Analytics: function() {
            return { trackEvent: trackEventFn };
          }
        }
      };
    }
  });

  QUnit.test("ko.extenders.addFieldTrackingGA", function(assert) {
    // arrange
    var testObservable = ko.observable(1).extend({
      addFieldTrackingGA: "Some button was clicked"
    });

    // prepare assertion    
    trackEventFn = function(prod, event, option, somebool) {
      assert.ok(true);
      // You can also assert on the argument values here
    }
    assert.expect(1); // Or more than 1, depending on the above

    // act
    testObservable(5);
  });

}());
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qunit/1.18.0/qunit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qunit/1.18.0/qunit.min.js"></script>

<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
```